# Find differences between two tables including duplicates

Tags: sql, hive

I have a query where I am able to find differences between two rows, but I also want to show duplicates rows as a difference. I know that table **actual_orders**  has duplicates and my table **expected_rows** does not have duplicates. How could I modify my query so it shows duplicates as a difference? And not only the actual data.

This is my query:

```
     select  
    expected_orders.mk_file_id,actual_orders.mk_file_id,
    expected_orders.ind_id, actual_orders.ind_id,
    expected_orders.mk_cust_id,actual_orders.mk_cust_id,
    expected_orders.order_sk,actual_orders.order_sk,
    expected_orders.progen_order_id,actual_orders.progen_order_id,
    expected_orders.order_chanel_id,actual_orders.order_chanel_id,
    expected_orders.order_date_str,actual_orders.order_date_str,
    expected_orders.order_total_usd,actual_orders.order_total_usd,
    expected_orders.order_ship_usd,actual_orders.order_ship_usd,
    expected_orders.order_discount_usd,actual_orders.order_discount_usd,
    expected_orders.order_tax_usd,actual_orders.order_tax_usd,
    expected_orders.empty_source_code,actual_orders.empty_source_code,
    expected_orders.method_of_payment_code,actual_orders.method_of_payment_code,
    expected_orders.feed_id,actual_orders.feed_id,
    expected_orders.creation_date_str,actual_orders.creation_date_str,
    expected_orders.update_ts_str,actual_orders.update_ts_str,
    expected_orders.empty_match_type,actual_orders.empty_match_type,
    expected_orders.mp_id,actual_orders.mp_id
    from default.expected_orders
    FULL OUTER JOIN default.actual_orders
    ON (
       COALESCE(expected_orders.mk_file_id,-1)=COALESCE(actual_orders.mk_file_id,-1) AND 
       COALESCE(expected_orders.ind_id,-1)=COALESCE(actual_orders.ind_id,-1)AND 
        COALESCE(expected_orders.mk_cust_id,'-1')=COALESCE(actual_orders.mk_cust_id,'-1') AND
        COALESCE(expected_orders.order_sk,-1)=COALESCE(actual_orders.order_sk,-1)

    )where (
    COALESCE(expected_orders.mk_file_id,-1)<>COALESCE(actual_orders.mk_file_id,-1) OR
    COALESCE(expected_orders.ind_id,-1)<>COALESCE(actual_orders.ind_id,-1) OR
    COALESCE(expected_orders.mk_cust_id,'-1')<>COALESCE(actual_orders.mk_cust_id,'-1') OR
    COALESCE(expected_orders.order_sk,-1)<>COALESCE(actual_orders.order_sk,-1) OR
    COALESCE(expected_orders.progen_order_id,'-1')<>COALESCE(actual_orders.progen_order_id,'-1') OR
    COALESCE(expected_orders.order_chanel_id,-1)<>COALESCE(actual_orders.order_chanel_id,-1) OR
    COALESCE(expected_orders.order_date_str,'-1')<>COALESCE(actual_orders.order_date_str,'-1') OR
    COALESCE(expected_orders.order_total_usd,0.0)<>COALESCE(actual_orders.order_total_usd,0.0) OR
    COALESCE(expected_orders.order_ship_usd,0.0)<>COALESCE(actual_orders.order_ship_usd,0.0)  OR
    COALESCE(expected_orders.order_discount_usd,0.0)<>COALESCE(actual_orders.order_discount_usd,0.0) OR
    COALESCE(expected_orders.order_tax_usd,0.0)<>COALESCE(actual_orders.order_tax_usd,0.0) OR
    COALESCE(expected_orders.empty_source_code,'-1')<>COALESCE(actual_orders.empty_source_code,'-1') OR
    COALESCE(expected_orders.method_of_payment_code,'-1')<>COALESCE(actual_orders.method_of_payment_code,'-1') OR
    COALESCE(expected_orders.feed_id,-1)<>COALESCE(actual_orders.feed_id,-1) OR
    COALESCE(expected_orders.creation_date_str,'-1')<>COALESCE(actual_orders.creation_date_str,'-1') OR
    COALESCE(expected_orders.update_ts_str,'-1')<>COALESCE(actual_orders.update_ts_str,'-1') OR
    COALESCE(expected_orders.empty_match_type,'-1')<>COALESCE(actual_orders.empty_match_type,'-1') OR
    COALESCE(expected_orders.mp_id,-1)<>COALESCE(actual_orders.mp_id,-1) )
```

I am using hive, but I am also going to include other tags like SQL and Progress. Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: For equality including NULL equal NULL, use `<=>`

Comment: Add count(*) column for calculating number of duplicates and compare it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a high-level summary

```
select      total_rows
           ,expected_rows
           ,actual_rows
           ,record_variations
           ,count (*)               as number_of_keys

from       (select      count (*)                               as total_rows
                       ,count (case when tab = 'E' then 1 end)  as expected_rows
                       ,count (case when tab = 'A' then 1 end)  as actual_rows
                       ,count (distinct rec)                    as record_variations

            from        (           select 'E' as tab,struct(*) as rec,mk_file_id,ind_id,mk_cust_id,order_sk from expected_orders
                        union all   select 'A' as tab,struct(*) as rec,mk_file_id,ind_id,mk_cust_id,order_sk from actual_orders
                        ) t

            group by    mk_file_id 
                       ,ind_id    
                       ,mk_cust_id
                       ,order_sk  
            ) t

group by    total_rows
           ,expected_rows
           ,actual_rows
           ,record_variations
;
```

and then drill down

```
select      mk_file_id 
           ,ind_id    
           ,mk_cust_id
           ,order_sk  

           ,count (*)                               as total_rows
           ,count (case when tab = 'E' then 1 end)  as expected_rows
           ,count (case when tab = 'A' then 1 end)  as actual_rows
           ,count (distinct rec)                    as record_variations


from        (           select 'E' as tab,struct(*) as rec,mk_file_id,ind_id,mk_cust_id,order_sk from expected_orders
            union all   select 'A' as tab,struct(*) as rec,mk_file_id,ind_id,mk_cust_id,order_sk from actual_orders
            ) t

group by    mk_file_id 
           ,ind_id    
           ,mk_cust_id
           ,order_sk  

-- having   ...
;
```

Comment: Hi, did you take a look on this suggestion?